# Debian Install on an Intel Apollo Lake CPU

Tags: intel, bios, secure-boot

I am encountering issues with the installation of Debian on this CPU.

The pc is [an Awow Lone Ultrabook tablet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0774KV3BR), with an Apollo Lake N3450 CPU,  [see here for further comments](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Celeron-N3450-Notebook-Processor.182737.0.html). Reading [Debian's official port page](https://www.debian.org/ports/) I gathered that Intel's Pentium and Celeron are **not** served by the *ia64* port, but by the standard *amd64* port. So I *dd*'ed a recent Debian image onto an USB key, and away I went. But the pc above simply refuses to boot from the USB key.

I did all the usual, standard things: checked signature and hashes of the downloaded ISO images, of the USB key (by *reverse-dd*-ing the image onto a different disk file and *then* re-checking hashes), booting a different pc from the same key (works flawlessly), disabling SecureBoot onto the pc. But no luck.

There is (*perhaps*) one strange thing, the boot manager on the pc is [Rod Smith's eRFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), which I had never seen before in a Windowsy environment, but then perhaps this is due exclusively to my limited experience.

Googling around, I found [this particular page](https://www.cnx-software.com/2017/02/07/installing-ubuntu-17-04-on-chuwi-lapbook-14-1-apollo-lake-laptop/) where a Linux installation is performed on a similar CPU, but at the very outset the guy states:

> The instructions below do not work with the newly manufactured models because ... The company also disabled the Linux option in the BIOS

and, lo and behold, the same applies to my pc, which offers as possible OS choices *Windows 10, Windows 7, DOS, Android*.

Does this mean I will have to endure the slings and arrows of outrageous Microsoft? Or has someone found a way around these problems?

Comment: I am running OpenBSD in a previous version of that architecture/CPU. Kali also boot pretty well *after* tinkering with the BIOS; in a cheap Lenovo however.

Comment: I suggest setting it as "Android". Ubuntu 16.04.3 installed and worked fine in a Celeron J1900 which is of the infamous Bay Trail family. Fortunately I have the first (good) revision of the Chuwi 14", the same mentioned in the CNX-Software article.

Answer (score 1):

Check this guide, maybe it can help you. I can't find how to modify to install debian, because i'm not familiarized with debian. https://thanhsiang.org/faqing/node/221

If you get it, please share the solution.

Comment: Note: The routes of this guide was wrong. To fix it:
At step 3 :- route is /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi instead of "/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi"

Get EasyUEFI portable through google (Others may don't work)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out to  me, I had somehow missed it. It looks preternaturally complex, so I will have to work on it, and (hopefully) trim it a bit. But thanks again, I´ll let you know. +1 for now.